# PowerMock: how to suppress parent methods on a Spy?

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, powermockito

How do I correctly suppress a parent class method on a Spy?

If I have a class Parent:

```
public class Parent {
    public void method() {
    System.out.println("Parent.method");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
@Override
    public void method() {
        super.method();
        System.out.println("Child.method");
    }
}
```

that I test with the following code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Parent.class)
public class SuppressParentTest {
   @Spy Child child = new Child();

   @Test
   public void testSuppressSuperclassMethods() {
       PowerMockito.suppress(methodsDeclaredIn(Parent.class));
       child.method();
   }
```

I get the following printout from System.out:

```
Parent.method
Child.method
```

whereas I should only get a printout of `Child.method`.

Interestingly if I delete the `@Spy` annotation from the declaration of the Child object, then `Parent.method()` is correctly suppressed.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I misunderstand how to use PowerMock?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the ordering.

In your test, Powermock is first creating the `Child` `Spy`, and afterwards you ask him to supress the methods of `Parent`. It seems that it is too late at that point, as the `Child` instance has already been created.

If you first call the `suppress` and then create the `Child`, it works:

```
@Test
public void testSuppressSuperclassMethods() {
    PowerMockito.suppress(MemberMatcher.methodsDeclaredIn(Parent.class));
    Child child = spy(Child.class);
    child.method();
}
```

Comment: Using `spy` method from `Mockito` worked, `spy` from `PowerMokito` not working, Thanks @Ruben